# Moving DB Log destination?

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I currently have SQL DB and Log files going to the same drive.  I would like to move the Log files to their own drive.   Is there an easy way to achieve this and will it require downtime/reboot of the server?

Comment: Instructions from Microsoft. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms345408(v=sql.130).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please don't detach and attach your database. If you detach it and something happens to it, you now have zero copies of your database. Much safer approaches:

---

## Backup/Restore

```
USE master;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE floob TO DISK = 'c:\wherever\floob.bak' WITH INIT, COPY_ONLY;

ALTER DATABASE floob SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE floob FROM DISK = 'c:\wherever\floob.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, 
  MOVE N'floob_log' TO 'c:\new_path\floob.ldf';
```

---

## Offline/Online

(You should still take a backup prior to doing this.)

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE floob SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

ALTER DATABASE floob MODIFY FILE 
  (name = N'floob_log', filename = 'c:\new_path\floob.ldf');

ALTER DATABASE floob SET OFFLINE;
```

Now go to Windows Explorer, **copy** the ldf file to the new location, and rename the original. Make sure the SQL Server service account has adequate permissions on the new folder. Then:

```
ALTER DATABASE floob SET ONLINE;

ALTER DATABASE floob SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Once the database is back up and running, you can safely delete the log file from the source location.

---

Both methods will need a brief downtime (how much depends on a lot of factors, including size of the database and speed of I/O both on the drives themselves and whatever path is between them), but neither will require you to reboot the server.